# Dropdown menu using HTML and CSS with image logo

Tags: html, css

I'm currently struggling making a dropdown menu for a website. The logo for the navigator is using img  tag since it's an image. PS: I did not put any styling for navigator itself. I also need an image after the navigator hence, in the section tag I put a div with a class "text-box". The only part on the navigator/website that has a dropdown menu is the "Book now" buttons. See below the desired layout as well as the codes. [sample layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JClHJ.jpg)

```
<body class="prevent-select">
      <section class="header">
         <nav>
            <a href="framedl.html"><img src="framelogo1.png" alt="Frame Development Logo" class="logo"></a>
            <div class="nav-links"  id="navLinks">
               <i class="fa fa-times" onclick="hideMenu()"></i>
               <ul>
                 <li><a href="framedl.html" class="hm">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="" class="tr">Gallery</a></li>
                 <li><a href="" class="ptrs">Services</a></li>
                 <li><a href="" class="abt">About Us</a></li>
                 <li><a href="" class="abt">Book Now</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="" >Music Video</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" >Photography</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" >Website Development</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" >Graphic Design</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" >Commercial</a></li>
                        <li><a href="" >Marketing Content</a></li>
                    </ul>
                 </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
                <i class="fa fa-bars" onclick="showMenu()"></i>
          </nav>
           <div class="text-box">
              <h1>Who To Visit?</h1>
              <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Et sint excepturi quisquam deleniti quibusdam officiis vel, consequatur rerum facere laboriosam! Dolores repudiandae voluptas libero explicabo dolorum placeat, natus amet voluptate.
              Libero laboriosam, expedita impedit perferendis aliquid quas fugiat numquam deserunt sed iure sit optio quis omnis. Minus quod praesentium similique, alias tempora eveniet ipsa dicta placeat consequuntur. Necessitatibus, libero. Harum!</p>
              <a href="" class="btn">Book Now</a>
           </div>
        </section>
    </body>
```

```
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.header{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4, 9, 30, 0.788), rgba(4,9,30,0.7)), url(bannerfp.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}
.text-box{
    width: 90%;
    color: aliceblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.text-box p{
    font-size: 62px;
}
.text-box p{
    margin: 10px 0 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: aliceblue;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.logo{
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 120px;
}
```

I tried following some online tutorials but the dropdown menu doesn't work. Additional question is it also possible making a dropdown menu using flexbox?

Comment: How is the menu supposed to show? CSS hover ? JS? Can you share the js for 'hideMenu' (as well as 'showMenu' if any)?